# jQuery Mobile: target Google Map markers from another page's list

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-markers

I'm creating a web app with jQuery Mobile. It contains a set of subpages, one of which is a map. This map page is a link to a map.js file in which a Google Maps API3 map is created. The markers are points-of-interest in a city; they're set up in an array. I've found an online demo of creating a side bar that lists the title of each marker.

I'd like to create a #page within my html file to hold the list so that clicking on a line in the list (like Chamber of Commerce) will transition to the map page and invoke that marker's info bubble. (This is the behavior of an entry on the sidebar list, as per the demo. I just want to have the list on a separate page so a click invokes the map.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My partner created this [Dynamic Markers, Geocoding and jQuery Google Maps Plugin tutorial](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4p2). It also includes some PhoneGap and Android specifics, but the jQuery Mobile and Google Maps should work on any platform.

Comment: Paul, that's interesting and above my head. It doesn't seem to handle the same challenge I'm trying to solve.